# How do you show that $P^{-1}x$ is an eigenvector of B corresponding to A if $ B$ is similar to $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $\lambda$ and $x$ are respectively corresponding eigenvalue and eigenvector for A. If  $ B$ ~ $A$, how do you show that  $P^{-1}x$ is an eigenvector of B corresponding to A?

Beginning the question, I substitute $A$ with $\lambda $. Since $\lambda$ here is a number, the equation becomes $B=\lambda I$. So how would you determine that $P^{-1}x$ is the particular eigenvector?

Comment: Please include more details. What does $B \sim A$ mean? What is the object $P$?

Comment: What did you mean by  **eigenvector of  B corresponding to A** ? Does it ha any specific definition or just the  definition of  eigen vector of  B ?

Comment: Most likely you have omitted some crucial information in setting up the problem, e.g. the exact relationship of $P$ with the similarity of $B$ and $A$.  If you were to write that $B = P^{-1}A P$ and that $Ax = \lambda x$, then something along the lines of $P^{-1}x$ being an eigenvector of $B$ will emerge quickly from a direct computation.

Answer (score 0):

If $B = P^{-1}AP$ and $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then
$$B(P^{-1}x) = P^{-1}A(PP^{-1}x) = P^{-1}Ax = \lambda P^{-1}x.$$